# Db2 11.5.6.0 on AIX 7.1 - How to guess size of full and incremental backup images?

Tags: db2, backup

Db2 11.5.6.0 on AIX 7.1
Is there any way to guess size of full and incremental backup images?

Answer (score 0):

No way.
There is no ability to get count of a tablespace pages changed since the last full or incremental backup.
There is only a flag (`TrackmodeState` column in the `db2pd -db mydb -tablesp` output) available for whole tablespace.